# "Message" : "Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

I got this error when i send a parameter from jQuery to WebMethod

*{"Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter:      \u0027personelName\u0027.","StackTrace":"   at           System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at    System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}*

My aspx page

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"                  CodeBehind="denemeAutoComp.aspx.cs" Inherits="AutoCompleteDeneme.denemeAutoComp"        %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="Style/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet"   type="text/css" />
<script src="Script/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Script/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript">    
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#txtPersonelName').autocomplete({

            source: function (request, response) {

                $.ajax({

                   url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/PersonelService.asmx/GetPersonelNames") %>',
                    data: "{ 'searchTerm': '" + request.term + "' }",
                     type: "POST",
                     dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (result) {
                        response(result.d);
                    },

                    error: function (result) {
                        alert('there is a problem processing your request');
                        alert(result.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }




        });
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="font-family: Arial" class="divAuto">
        Name:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPersonelName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="gvPersonels" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>


    </div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My Web Service(PersonelService.asmx)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Script.Services;

namespace AutoCompleteDeneme
{

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX,      uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class PersonelService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public List<string> GetPersonelNames(string personelName)
    {

        string CS =   ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        List<string> personelNames = new List<string>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetMatchingPersonelNames", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@PersonelName", personelName);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                personelNames.Add(rdr["adi"].ToString());

            }
        }
        return personelNames;


    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using JSON, all strings have to be enclosed in double quotes `"`, not single quotes `'`. `\u0027` is a single quote, and is probably what the API is complaining about. So if you replace

`data: "{ 'searchTerm': '" + request.term + "' }",`

with

`data: '{ "searchTerm": "' + request.term + '" }',`

It might work.

Comment: it did not work unfortunately :( there might be more errors maybe :(

Comment: i have inspired your advice and found a solution thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To solve this error you must make sure that:
1. the parameter sent to the function has the same name as the param the function gets.
2.the parameter sent to the function must have the same "type" the function gets.
3. `json.stringify(param)` will be only on the right side of json expression.

Code example simplify:

//function

```
 [WebMethod]

public static doSomethimg(string[] myParam){}
```

//data in jquery
*make* sure the param is an array (in this case)

```
data:{myParam:json.stringify(myArr)},
```

Comment: +!, it is even applicable if we are passing a model as parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You should be passing the same method parameter from GetPersonelNames, in your Ajax call

```
data: "{ 'personelName': '" + "your data" + "' }"
```

Comment: ... and @Bjorn Roberg is correct about the quotes.  [When using JSON, all strings have to be enclosed in double quotes ", not single quotes ']  ASP.NET will (sometimes) tolerate single quotes when parsing JSON but they are not correct.

Answer (score 0):

it is done with a change !

Instead of

```
 data: "{ 'searchTerm': '" + request.term + "' }",
```

This code works

```
data: JSON.stringify({
                        personelName : request.term
                    }),
```