# "Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027name\u0027

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, ajax

I'm Using Ajax to call a server side method but i keep getting this error

> {"Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027name\u0027.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}

this is the client side

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "Server.aspx/sendEmail",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ name: "foo", company: "bar", country: "foo", email: "bar", msg: "bla" }),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var a = 3;
        },
        error: function (a, b) {
            var a = 43;
        }
    });
});
```

and this is the server side

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public static string sendEmail(string name, string company, string country, string email, string msg)
{

}
```

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30597028/message-invalid-web-service-call-missing-value-for-parameter-u0027

Comment: First one didn't help and for the second one. you can see i have the same name in the javascrip and the webmethod

Comment: Have you seen link which i have pasted here

Comment: Instead of this data: JSON.stringify({ name: "foo", company: "bar", country: "foo", email: "bar", msg: "bla" }) use data: JSON.stringify({ "name": "foo", "company": "bar", "country": "foo", "email": "bar", "msg": "bla" })

Comment: And add type :"GET/POST" property

Comment: Unfortunately both not working

Comment: Have you check the link

Comment: I have checked them both

Comment: Could you remove this line from code behind [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]

Comment: No because it will give me this error

{"Message":"An attempt was made to call the method \u0027sendEmail\u0027 using a GET request, which is not allowed.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData methodData, HttpContext context)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
when using a GET function through ajax you dont need to send json because Jquery will do it for you.
so you need to remove the contentType attribute and make the data one like this:

```
data: { name: "foo", company: "bar", country: "foo", email: "bar", msg: "bla" },
```